# mail.ru requires a password for third-party applications, although the program uses it

Tags: python, mail.ru, smtplib

```
def report():
    sender = 'email@mail.ru'
    receiver = 'email@yandex.ru'
    password = 'password for third-party applications'
    message = 'Bruh'
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.ru', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
report()
```

Comment: требуется перевод текста ошибки?

Comment: нет, перевод не требуется